# IPhone app that allows search for string inside .js,.html files?

Tags: search, text, text-editor

Is there any app that allows me search for string inside huge list of .js,.html,.php files without opening individual files?I have tried an app called Documents to no avail.

(Just like Search for Text Inside of Any File Using Windows Search)

Comment: Where are those files stored? (i.e. are they on iCloud Drive, Dropbox, locally stored within the sandbox of an app on the phone, or?)

Comment: pretty sure that the iPhone search can do that if you have the file downloaded, or the search in iCloud drive?

Comment: Thanks for reply it is stored within the sandbox of an app and i can open it in any app if they can search .js or .html files. Document app can search for string inside .java files but not .js!

Comment: Maybe if you rename it to .txt? After all, they're all just text files.

Comment: Well some time i don't know which file (huge list of .js and .html)to look for specific string so i cant waste time converting all to txt unless there be a program in iPhone to convert all files inside a folder to txt!